# How to map key and values from two files?

Tags: java, file, jackson, mapping, deserialization

I have searched around but couldn't find any similar question so I am posting a new one.

Currently I have basically two files. One file is the definition of the key, another file is the value that maps to the key (`CSV` format, but I'd like to not restrict it `CSV` file).

File 1:

`id:TEXT,name:TEXT,city:TEXT,state:TEXT,zip:Integer`

What it means is that the file has 5 fields, it defines the `id` of type `TEXT`, `name` of type `TEXT`, `zip` of type `Integer`, etc.

File 2 (each record is separated by a new line, there will be thousands of lines record):

`11212, karen, new york, NY, 10000`

`21312, jim, boston, MA, 10000`

`12312,,seattle,,10000 // name and state is not available in this record`

So the file 2 will have the value that maps to the key in file 1, notice if the value is `null` or empty, it will just be ignored in the result.

What would be an element way to convert these files into a java object as below:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class RecordCollection {
    // Key is to map to the `id`, whereas the rest of the values map to Record
    Map<String, Record> records;
}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Record {
    String name;
    String city;
    String state;
    Integer zip;
}
```

To start I have:

`String keyValues = "id:TEXT,name:TEXT,city:TEXT,state:TEXT,zip:Integer";`

Now I have the inputStream parsed for file 2 and here is where I am at:

`BufferedReader file2InputStreamBuffered = new BufferedReader("file 2");`

Now, how to map the value to my `Java` objects in an elegant way? (With 3rd party tools or any common libs)

Comment: Why you need to keep keyValues as "id:TEXT,name:TEXT,city:TEXT,state:TEXT,zip:Integer";
is it going to change or will be fixed?

Comment: @SagarKharab it will be fixed. `keyValues` are defined to reduce the noise of parsing file 1.

Comment: If you know it will always be fixed then can you not use stream to map it to your object. 
`    try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(file2Name))) {
        List<Record> records = stream.map(s -> {
            String[] values = s.split(",");
            return Record.builder().name(values[1]).city(values[2]).state(values[3]).zip(values[4]).build();
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to build `CsvSchema` for your format file and after that use it for reading `CSV` file. Code could look like below:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MappingIterator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvSchema;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class CsvApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File formatFile = new File("./resource/test.format").getAbsoluteFile();
        File csvFile = new File("./resource/test.csv").getAbsoluteFile();

        CsvSchema schema = createSchemaForFormat(formatFile);

        CsvMapper csvMapper = new CsvMapper();
        MappingIterator<Record> rows = csvMapper.readerFor(Record.class).with(schema).readValues(csvFile);

        RecordCollection recordCollection = new RecordCollection(100);
        while (rows.hasNext()) {
            recordCollection.add(rows.next());
        }

        recordCollection.getRecords().forEach((k, v) -> {
            System.out.println(k + " => " + v);
        });
    }

    private static CsvSchema createSchemaForFormat(File formatFile) throws IOException {
        String content = String.join("", Files.readAllLines(formatFile.toPath()));
        String[] columns = content.split(",");

        CsvSchema.Builder builder = CsvSchema.builder();
        for (String column : columns) {
            String[] columnData = column.split(":");
            String name = columnData[0];
            String type = columnData[1];
            builder.addColumn(name, "Integer".equalsIgnoreCase(type) ? CsvSchema.ColumnType.NUMBER : CsvSchema.ColumnType.STRING);
        }

        return builder.build();
    }
}

class RecordCollection {

    private final Map<String, Record> records;

    RecordCollection(int expectedSize) {
        this.records = new HashMap<>(expectedSize);
    }

    public void add(Record record) {
        this.records.put(record.getId(), record);
    }

    public Map<String, Record> getRecords() {
        return records;
    }
}

class Record {

    private final String id;
    private final String name;
    private final String city;
    private final String state;
    private final Integer zip;

    @JsonCreator
    public Record(
            @JsonProperty("id") String id,
            @JsonProperty("name") String name,
            @JsonProperty("city") String city,
            @JsonProperty("state") String state,
            @JsonProperty("zip") Integer zip) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.city = city;
        this.state = state;
        this.zip = zip;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public Integer getZip() {
        return zip;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Record{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", city='" + city + '\'' +
                ", state='" + state + '\'' +
                ", zip=" + zip +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
12312 => Record{name='     ', city='seattle ', state='  ', zip=10000}
21312 => Record{name='jim  ', city='boston  ', state='MA', zip=10000}
11212 => Record{name='karen', city='new york', state='NY', zip=10000}
```

In above case `Record` class is tied with configuration file which defines columns. If format of `CSV` is not dynamic you can build schema in `Java` class without reading it from file. If it is dynamic, instead of `Record` class you could store `Map<String, Object>` type which could handle dynamic columns.

For more information take a look od [Jackson CSV documentation](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-text/tree/master/csv).